# A Button's state in main page isn't being updated properly

Tags: flutter

So I have two pages currently which is main.dart and second_page.dart, I'm also using a provider class (provider_class.dart) to store and pass around variable values and a Button class(Button_Data.dart) to create a button. The problem seems to be a logic problem where when I navigate back from the second page by pressing the 'Return to previous page' button on the first time the second page is loaded it doesn't update the state of button 'Sell and Collect' to enabled. For it to update the 'Sell and Collect' button's state to enabled the user needs to navigate/load up the second page a second time before the 'Sell and Collect' button is updated when navigating back to the main page.

How can I make it so that the state of the 'Sell and Collect' button is updated to enabled whenever the user navigates from the second page to the main page regardless if the second page has been visited already?

main.dart

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:provider/provider.dart';
import '../Classes/provider_class.dart';// Import the provider class
import '../Classes/Button_Data.dart';
import 'second_page.dart';


void main() {
  runApp(
    ChangeNotifierProvider(
      create: (context) => PageProvider(),
      child: MaterialApp(
        home: MainPage(),
      ),
    ),
  );
}


class MainPage extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    // Get the PageProvider instance from the Provider
    PageProvider pageProvider = Provider.of<PageProvider>(context);

    // Now you can access pageProvider.firstPageActiveButtons[1] and other properties

    final List<Button_Data> buttonsData = [
      Button_Data('Check Inventory', pageProvider.firstPageActiveButtons[0]),
      Button_Data('Sell and Collect', pageProvider.firstPageActiveButtons[1]),
      Button_Data('Distribute POSM', pageProvider.firstPageActiveButtons[2]),
      Button_Data('Remit Sales', pageProvider.firstPageActiveButtons[3]),
      Button_Data('Return and Restock', pageProvider.firstPageActiveButtons[4]),
      Button_Data('Get ending Inventory', pageProvider.firstPageActiveButtons[5]),
    ];

    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('EX Trucker Tasks'),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: buttonsData.map((buttonData) => CustomButton(
            key: PageStorageKey<String>(buttonData.name),
            buttonData: buttonData,
            onTap: () {
              if (buttonData.name == 'Check Inventory') {
                Navigator.pushReplacement(
                  context,
                  MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => SecondPage()),
                );
              } else {
                print('Button ${buttonData.name} pressed!');
              }
            },
          )).toList(),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}


class CustomButton extends StatelessWidget {
  final Button_Data buttonData;
  final VoidCallback onTap;

  CustomButton({Key? key, required this.buttonData, required this.onTap})
      : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      margin: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 10),
      child: ElevatedButton(
        onPressed: buttonData.isEnabled ? onTap : null,
        style: ButtonStyle(
          backgroundColor:
          buttonData.isEnabled ? null : MaterialStateProperty.all<Color>(Colors.grey),
        ),
        child: Text(buttonData.name),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

second_page.dart

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:shared_preferences/shared_preferences.dart';
import '../Classes/Button_Data.dart';
import 'main.dart';
import 'package:provider/provider.dart';
import '../Classes/provider_class.dart'; // Import the provider class

class SecondPage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _SecondPageState createState() => _SecondPageState();
}

class _SecondPageState extends State<SecondPage>
    with AutomaticKeepAliveClientMixin<SecondPage> {
  late List<Button_Data> secondPageButtonsData;
  bool showReturnButton = false;

  @override
  bool get wantKeepAlive => true;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    initializeSecondPage();
  }

  bool isFirstLoad = true;

  Future<void> initializeSecondPage() async {
    PageProvider pageProvider = Provider.of<PageProvider>(context, listen: false);
    await loadStoredState();

    // Enable buttons up to the active index when the page is loaded for the first time
    if (isFirstLoad) {
      for (int i = 0; i < secondPageButtonsData.length; i++) {
        secondPageButtonsData[i].isEnabled = i <= pageProvider.secondPageActiveButtonIndex;
      }
      showReturnButton = pageProvider.secondPageActiveButtonIndex == secondPageButtonsData.length - 1;
      isFirstLoad = false;
      print('isFirstLoad is true');
    } else {
      print('isFirstLoad is false');
    }
  }

  Future<void> loadStoredState() async {
    secondPageButtonsData = [
      Button_Data('Task 1', true),
      Button_Data('Task 2', false),
      Button_Data('Task 3', false),
      Button_Data('Task 4', false),
      Button_Data('Task 5', false),
    ];

    final prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();

    for (int i = 0; i < secondPageButtonsData.length; i++) {
      Map<String, dynamic>? storedData = await retrieveStoredState(secondPageButtonsData[i].name);
      if (storedData != null) {
        secondPageButtonsData[i].isEnabled = storedData['isEnabled'] ?? false;
      }
    }

    showReturnButton = secondPageButtonsData.last.isEnabled;
  }

  void storeState(Button_Data buttonData) async {
    final prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    prefs.setBool('${buttonData.name}_isEnabled', buttonData.isEnabled);
  }

  Future<Map<String, dynamic>?> retrieveStoredState(String buttonName) async {
    final prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    bool? isEnabled = prefs.getBool('${buttonName}_isEnabled');
    if (isEnabled != null) {
      return {'isEnabled': isEnabled};
    } else {
      return null;
    }
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    super.build(context);
    PageProvider pageProvider = Provider.of<PageProvider>(context);

    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('Check Inventory'),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: [
            for (int i = 0; i < secondPageButtonsData.length && pageProvider.isFirstLoad; i++)
              Row(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                children: [
                  if (i == pageProvider.secondPageActiveButtonIndex && !showReturnButton)
                    Container(
                      margin: EdgeInsets.only(right: 8.0),
                      width: 8.0,
                      height: 8.0,
                      decoration: BoxDecoration(
                        shape: BoxShape.circle,
                        color: Colors.red,
                      ),
                    ),
                  CustomButton(
                    buttonData: secondPageButtonsData[i],
                    onTap: () {
                      setState(() {
                        if (i == pageProvider.secondPageActiveButtonIndex &&
                            i < secondPageButtonsData.length - 1) {
                          // Check if the correct button is pressed to increment the index
                          pageProvider.setSecondPageActiveButtonIndex(i + 1);
                          secondPageButtonsData[pageProvider.secondPageActiveButtonIndex].isEnabled = true;
                          storeState(secondPageButtonsData[pageProvider.secondPageActiveButtonIndex]);

                          // Change the text on the button to "Task completed"
                          secondPageButtonsData[i].name = 'Task ${pageProvider.secondPageActiveButtonIndex} completed';
                        } else if (i == secondPageButtonsData.length - 1) {
                          // Show 'Return to previous page' button when 'Task 5' is pressed
                          secondPageButtonsData[i].name = 'Task 5 completed';
                          showReturnButton = true;
                        }
                      });
                    },
                  ),
                ],
              ),

            // Other widgets go here

            if (!pageProvider.isFirstLoad) // Show the Text widgets when isFirstLoad is false
              ...[
                Text('Task 1 complete', style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20)),
                Text('Task 2 complete', style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20)),
                Text('Task 3 complete', style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20)),
                Text('Task 4 complete', style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20)),
                Text('Task 5 complete', style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20)),
              ],

            // 'Return to previous page' button
            if ((showReturnButton || !pageProvider.isFirstLoad) )
              ElevatedButton(
                onPressed: () async {
                  await Navigator.pushReplacement(
                    context,
                    MaterialPageRoute(
                      builder: (context) => MainPage(),
                    ),
                  );
                  // Set isFirstLoad to false and notify listeners
                  pageProvider.setIsFirstLoad(false);
                  pageProvider.firstPageActiveButtons[1] = true;
                },
                child: Text('Return to previous page'),
              ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

provider_class.dart

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class PageProvider extends ChangeNotifier {
  int secondPageActiveButtonIndex = 0;
  int mainPageNoticeIndex = 0;

  // Declare a fixed-length list with a specified size and default values
  List<bool> firstPageActiveButtons = List<bool>.filled(6, false);

  bool isFirstLoad = true; // Added variable to track the first load

  PageProvider() {
    // Initialize the list or set its values in the constructor
    firstPageActiveButtons[0] = true;
    firstPageActiveButtons[1] = false;
    firstPageActiveButtons[2] = false;
    firstPageActiveButtons[3] = false;
    firstPageActiveButtons[4] = false;
    firstPageActiveButtons[5] = false;
  }

  void setSecondPageActiveButtonIndex(int index) {
    secondPageActiveButtonIndex = index;
    notifyListeners();
  }

  void setIsFirstLoad(bool value) {
    isFirstLoad = value; // Update the value of isFirstLoad
    notifyListeners();
  }
}
```

Button_Data.dart

```
class Button_Data {
  String name;
  bool isEnabled;

  Button_Data(this.name, this.isEnabled);
}
```

I tried modifying the logic in second_page.dart that handles what happens when you press the 'Return to previous page' button but the problem still persists. I expected the issue to be in the part where the 'Return to previous page' button modifies the value of 'pageProvider.firstPageActiveButtons[1]' to true but I'm beginning to think the logic problem might be in how the 'main page' is initialized.

Comment: `    super.build(context);` What??  Where did you see to do that?  Not sure if that's breaking anything, but start by removing that.

Answer (score 1):

issue might be related to Navigator.pushReplacement , in this if we use Navigator.pushReplacement then it was navigate back to main Page so Button State are not updated.

```
ElevatedButton(
  onPressed: () async {
    Navigator.pop(context);
    pageProvider.setIsFirstLoad(false);
    pageProvider.firstPageActiveButtons[1] = true;
    pageProvider.notifyListeners();
  },
  child: Text('Return to previous page'),
),
```

Comment: Tried it now it just results in a blank screen when I try navigating back to the main page by pressing the 'Return to previous page' button